# How to write Lambda expression for this SQL query?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following `SQL query`

```
   Select cLedgerName,dDateFrom,cPeriodType,nPeriodFrom,nPeriodTo
   from sys_Account_Ledger a,sys_Log_Deposits_Interest_Master b
   where a.cGLCode=b.cGLCode and b.dDateFrom='08-11-2012' and b.cPeriodType='Days'
```

I wanted to write this `query` using `Lambda expression`.This is where I am stuck.

```
public IList<ListViewData> GetDepositsListViewData(string glCode, string effectDate, string periodType)
        {
            using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                var data=db.sys_Account_Ledgers.Join(db.sys_Log_Deposits_Interest_Masters,
                    ledger=>ledger.cGLCode,
                    deposits=>deposits.cGLCode,
                    (ledger,deposits)=>new {db.sys_Account_Ledgers =ledger,db.sys_Log_Deposits_Interest_Masters =deposits}) 
            }
        }
```

I have created a `class` which will be the return type of my query.

Here is the `class`

```
public class ListViewData
        {
            public string LedgerName { get; set; }
            public string DateFrom { get; set; }
            public string PeriodType { get; set; }
            public int PeriodFrom { get; set; }
            public int PeriodTo { get; set; }
        }
```

Can anyone help me out with the `lambda expression`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = dataContext.SysAccountLedger
                        .Join(dataContext.SysLogDepositsInterestMaster,
                             a => a.cGlCode,
                             b => b.cGlCode,
                             (a, b) => new ListViewData
                             {
                                 LedgerName = a.LedgerName,
                                 DateFrom = b.DateFrom,
                                 PeriodType = b.PeriodType
                                 // other properties
                             })
                         .Where(item => item.DateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime("08-11-2012") && 
                                            item.PeriodType == "Days")
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,I will try it out and let you know.

Comment: I tried but I am able to only get LedgerName property and the other properties are blank.

Comment: @freebird, try using SQL Server profiler to see what is the query that gets sent to the database. Next, check if you have the correct assignment of properties and that indeed the returned values aren't null or empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Direct translation into Linq:

    var query = from a in db.sys_Account_Ledger
        join b in db.sys_Log_Deposits_Interest_Master on a.cGLCode equals b.cGLCode
        where b.dDateFrom == Convert.ToDateTime("08-11-2012") && b.cPeriodType == "Days"
        select new { a, b };

//Lambda of this:

var query = db.sys_AccountLedger
    .Join(db.sys_Log_Deposits_Interest_Master, 
        a => a.cGLCode, 
        b => b.cGLCode, 
        (a, b) => new {a , b})
    .Where(w => w.dDateFrom == Convert.ToDateTime("08-11-2012") && w.cPeriodType == "Days");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try this out and let you know.

Comment: I am only able to extract LedgerName property and other properties seem to be blank.